# Extract filename ending with tar.gz from a URL where URL and filename changes frequently

Tags: sed

Looking to extract the filename ending in tar.gz from a URL, where the URL, location and filename might frequently change.

```
https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/testing/snapshot-latest.tar.gz 
https://s3.eu-central-2.wasabisys.com/testing/support/testing.tar.gz
```

I thought of using cut and grep, but since the the amount of "/" change that is not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I extract the filename ending in tar.gz from a URL?

**Option 1:**

You can use `${url##*/}`:

```
$ url="https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/testing/snapshot-latest.tar.gz "; echo "${url##*/}"
snapshot-latest.tar.gz
$ url="https://s3.eu-central-2.wasabisys.com/testing/support/testing.tar.gz"; echo "${url##*/}"
testing.tar.gz
$
```

Source: [Extract the base file name from a URL using bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64435/95111), answer by [ManuelSchneid3r](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27330/manuelschneid3r)

**Option 2:**

`basename` also works with URLs:

```
$ url="https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/testing/snapshot-latest.tar.gz "; basename $url
snapshot-latest.tar.gz
$ url="https://s3.eu-central-2.wasabisys.com/testing/support/testing.tar.gz"; basename $url
testing.tar.gz
$
```

Source: [Extract the base file name from a URL using bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425413/95111) answer by [Frank Zdarsky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/274994/frank-zdarsky)

Comment: thanks works a treat and since it's running a dockefile I like the idea of not installing base name and just using echo. great help

Answer (score 0):

First: Separate string at `/` and print the last column with `awk`:

```
$echo "https://link/snapshot-latest.tar.gz" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
snapshot-latest.tar.gz
```

Second: Remove the last 7 characters if you want to cut "tar.gz":

```
$echo "https://link/snapshot-latest.tar.gz" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' | sed 's/.\{7\}$//'
snapshot-latest
```

Answer (score 0):

`basename` does just the job you need.

From [man 1 basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
NAME
       basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames
```

In your example:

```
$ basename https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com/testing/snapshot-latest.tar.gz
```

has `snapshot-latest.tar.gz` as output.

If you need to extract the basenames from a list of files, such as the ones obtained with ls, you can pipe the list to `xargs` as follows:

```
ls somedir/*.tar.gz |xargs -I {} basename {}
```